# System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString - "Parameter is not valid" exception

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

Sometimes Microsoft's exception messages are infuriatingly unhelpful. I have created a nice little MVC method to render text. The method body is below. When it reaches the "DrawString" method, I get an exception thrown saying "Parameter is not valid".

Note that the font, as best I can tell is constructed properly (I"m just using Arial at 10pt), the rect size is positive and valid looking, the brush is a white SolidBrush and the format flags do not affect the output; i.e. if I exclude the format flags from the call, I still get an error.

The DrawString call is right near the bottom.

```
public ActionResult RenderText(
    string fontFamily,
    float pointSize,
    string foreColor,
    string backColor,
    bool isBold,
    bool isItalic,
    bool isVertical,
    string align,
    string[] allText,
    int textIndex)
{
    // method renders a horizontal or vertical text image, taking all the text strings that will be rendered in each image
    // and sizing the final bitmap according to which text would take the most space, thereby making it possible to render
    // a selection of text images all at the same size.

    Response.ContentType = "image/png";

    var fmt = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
    if(isVertical)
        fmt.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;

    Func<string,StringAlignment> getAlign = (s => {
        switch(s.ToLower())
        {
            case "right": return StringAlignment.Far;
            case "center": return StringAlignment.Center;
            default: return StringAlignment.Near;
        }
    });
    fmt.LineAlignment = isVertical ? StringAlignment.Center : getAlign(align);
    fmt.Alignment = isVertical ? getAlign(align) : StringAlignment.Center;

    var strings = (allText ?? new string[0]).Where(t => t.Length > 0).ToList();
    if(strings.Count == 0)
        strings.Add("[Missing Text]");

    FontStyle style = FontStyle.Regular;
    if(isBold)
        if(isItalic)
            style = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic;
        else
            style = FontStyle.Bold;
    else if(isItalic)
        style = FontStyle.Italic;

    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, pointSize, style, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Color fc = foreColor.IsHexColorString() ? foreColor.ToColorFromHex() : foreColor.ToColor();
    Color bc = backColor.IsHexColorString() ? backColor.ToColorFromHex() : backColor.ToColor();

    var maxSize = new Size(0,0);
    using(var tmp = new Bitmap(100, 200))
        using(var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(tmp))
            foreach(var txt in strings)
            {
                var size = gfx.MeasureString(txt, font, 1000, fmt);
                maxSize = new Size(
                    Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(isVertical ? size.Height : size.Width), maxSize.Width),
                    Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(isVertical ? size.Width : size.Height), maxSize.Width)
                );
            }

    using(var bmp = new Bitmap(maxSize.Width, maxSize.Height))
    {
        using(var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gfx.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            var rect = new RectangleF(new PointF(0,0), maxSize);
            gfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bc), rect);
            gfx.DrawString(strings[textIndex], font, new SolidBrush(fc), rect, fmt);
        }
        bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Just a note: new SolidBrush(fc) will leak a Brush resource, it needs a using block too.

Comment: Just a tip : I had the same error "Parameter is not valid" and arrived on this thread. In my case it had nothing to do with the accepted answer, it was because I was passing to DrawString a Disposed instance of font or brush. The exception is not really helpful...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well I found out the cause of the problem. Something very obscure. The code works when I remove this line:

```
gfx.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
```

Comment: Life saver! This makes sense actually, I'm sure it needs blending enabled to draw text but it would be nice if the error message mentioned something about that :-)

Answer (score 4):

What could help while debugging, is making the methods smaller. For example, you could replace

```
FontStyle style = FontStyle.Regular;
if(isBold)
    if(isItalic)
        style = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic;
    else
        style = FontStyle.Bold;
else if(isItalic)
    style = FontStyle.Italic;
```

by

```
FontStyle style = GetFontStyle(isBold, isItalic);
```

and

```
public FontStyle GetFontStyle(bool isBold, bool isItalic)
{
    if(isBold)
        if(isItalic)
            return FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic;
        else
            return FontStyle.Bold;
    else if(isItalic)
        return FontStyle.Italic;
    else
        return FontStyle.Regular;
}
```

It makes your code more readable and it makes it more easy for others to help you.

Really no offense meant!

Kind regards,
Ans Vlug